# How can I use colspan in the footer with html5button export to excel or print?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, datatables

I have a table with 8 columns. I want to put a disclaimer for the table data in the footer. So in HTML I put

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="8">FOOTER MESSAGE</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

In the HTML view this looks great, but when I export it to excel using html5 it puts this in the footer over every column (so shows it 8 times). Is there a way to just get it once in the center? If not is there a way to just get it to show up once, but not in the center?

Thanks

Comment: Is the [post on the datatables.net forum](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/32565/how-can-i-use-colspan-in-the-footer-with-html5button-export-to-excel) yours?

Comment: No, I did not write it. But we have the same problem.